# CSS Dark Theme Media Queries not working on Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css, media-queries, darkmode

I recently switched my site to use media queries to change the site's theme from light mode to dark mode.

It works on the Edge browser for desktop and mobile, but doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome (desktop and mobile).

Why aren't these media queries working on Firefox and Chrome, and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

OS Windows 10 system theme is light
Chrome Version 90.0.4430.212
Firefox Version Version 88.0.1

```css
body {
  /* Black-on-white by default */
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* White-on-black if user prefers dark color scheme */
  body {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Hello, StackOverflow!</p>
```

Comment: Works for me. Chrome 90.0.4430.212 on Windows 10 with OS colour mode set to "Dark". Same for Firefox 88.0

Comment: Yes it works fine, would be helpful if you listed OS and exact versions. It's a major feature and wouldn't tend to just be broken. It's used on 1000s of projects already.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and my system is set to light. I changed Firefox and Chrome to dark and it didn't work :/

Comment: SOLVED! The problem was my System OS theme (Windows) was light theme. When Windows is dark theme, then it works

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Firefox also look at the theme preference of your operating system.

If you are on Windows with your operating system theme set to light, even if Chrome and Firefox are dark theme, they will not load webpages in dark theme.

If you change your Windows operating system theme to dark theme, then Chrome and Firefox will change.